# CatBoostRegressor is showing an error when trying to predict (TypeError: Cannot convert 'b' to float)

Tags: python, regression, catboost

So, here's the thing... I have a problem pretty close to what this guys was asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037639/not-working-when-value-that-to-be-predicted-is-categorical). I was building a pretty solid model. I actually have ran this code a few times, but now I'm facing this issue.

This is my dataset (I can't share any real data due to the company policy):

```
category        brand        city        day_of_week        price
mobile_phone    LG           Busan       3                  100   
mobile_phone    Apple        Seul        4                  120
mobile_phone    LG           Changwon    5                  110
tv              LG           Busan       2                  120
tv              Samsung      Suwon       3                  150
tv              Samsung      Ulsan       3                  200
.
.
.
```

It's about the price of fixing eletronics. The thing is that I was running a regression in which price was the target and the rest are the features.

So this is exactly what I've ran:

```
rf = CatBoostRegressor(
cat_features = ["category",
"brand",
"city",
"day_of_week"],
eval_metric="RMSE",
learning_rate=0.13,
iterations=500,
)

rf.fit(X_train, y_train, plot=True, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
pred_rf = rf.predict(X_test)
```

And this is the message Python presented:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert 'b'mobile_phone'' to float
```

Why is that? CatBoost should've converted without anything else there. And it's crazy because that was working like 10 minutes ago with another very similar dataset.

Also, the model actually ran:

```
bestTest = 0.3275576877
bestIteration = 144

Shrink model to first 145 iterations.
```

So, any idea what I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance. Again, sorry that I can't share the dataset.

Comment: It looks like you got your variable mixed up? The error is saying that it received a string value in the non-categorical value, and the most likely reason is human error: check if all x_train, x_test, ... are actually what they supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to check Chris' comment. I just had this error and it was because I hadn't specified my `cat_features` param properly. It looks like you have it correct at first glance, but what I do is pull out all object features using:

```
# Get all object variables from X_train
cat_vars = [var for var in X_train.columns if X_train[var].dtype == "O"]

# Initialize model with cat_vars
rf = CatBoostRegressor(
                   cat_features = cat_vars,
                   eval_metric="RMSE",
                   learning_rate=0.13,
                   iterations=500,
                   )
# Fit & Predict
rf.fit(X_train, y_train, plot=True, eval_set=(X_test, y_test))
pred_rf = rf.predict(X_test)
```

This way, if my dataframe was read in oddly (`pd.read_csv`) and converted some `dtype` that's normally `float` or `int` it will still process.
**Caution:** In prod you'd want to statically know your cat_vars and have them defined in some config file rather than running this. This is just for dev on catboost.